# How to print nested objects using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, nested-object

How does one go about printing the values of a nested object/property in a map on a JSP page using JSTL?

```xml
<c:foreach items="${survey}" var="survey">
    <c:out value="${survey.value}" />
</c:foreach>
```

`Survey` has a property called `Questions`, which is another bean, and I want to print those questions `survey.questions.getId()` or `survey.questions.getTitle()`), how would that `<c:forEach>` statement look like?

In my case, `${survey}` is a `Map` not a `Collection`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your nested property is a single object instance, you just reference it directly, like:

```
<c:forEach var="surveyItem" items="${surveys}">
    ${surveyItem.title} <!-- You can use the c:out if you really want to -->
</c:forEach>
```

That assumes that you have a collection of `Survey` objects bound to the `surveys` attribute, and that each `Survey` has a title.  It will print the title of each survey.

If your nested property is a collection of objects, then you use a `forEach` loop to iterate them, just like in your example.

```
<c:forEach var="question" items="${survey.questions}">
    ${question.title} 
</c:forEach>
```

That will print the title of each `Question`, assuming that you have a single `Survey` object bound to the `survey` attribute, and that the `Survey` object has a collection of `Question` objects as a field (with an appropriate getter method, i.e. `getQuestions()`).

You can also have nested loops, like:

```
<c:forEach var="surveyItem" items="${surveys}">
    ${surveyItem.title}
    <c:forEach var="question" items="${surveyItem.questions}">
        ${question.title} 
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

That will print the title of every `Survey` along with the title of each `Question` in each `Survey`.

And if for some reason you decide to pass a `Map`, you can do:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${surveyMap}">
    Map Key:  ${entry.key}
    Map Value:  ${entry.value}
    Nested Property:  ${entry.value.title}
    Nested Collection:
    <c:forEach var="question" items="${entry.value.questions}">
        ${question.title}
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Can u please how this would change if survey is a map?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to iterate two times in the loops if your Survey.Question is another collection objects. For example,

```
<c:foreach items="${survey}" var="survey">

    <c:out value="${survey.value}" />

    <c:foreach items="${survey.Question" var="question">
      $<c:question.item> or $<c:question.title>
     </c:foreach>
</c:foreach>
```