# show map data using jstl in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

**MyServlet.java**

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, MyObj>> lhm = 
                    new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Bank>>();
LinkedHashMap<String, MyObj> lhmObj = new LinkedHashMap<String, Bank>();

lhmObj.put(arg1, arg2);
lhm.put(arg3, lhmObj);

request.setAttribute("Map", lhm);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**index.jsp**

```
<c:forEach items="${Map}" var="myMap">
  <c:out value="${myMap.key}"></c:out>
  <c:out value="${myMap.value}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

I wrote this code and worked successfully but this showed:

```
ADD {213412=my.package.directory.MyObj@2e6d441d,
       213413=my.package.directory.MyObj@792e3bb}
```

I want to show the data which is in the MyObj. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  `<c:out value="${myMap.value}"></c:out>`

Your `${myMap.value}` returning another `map  i.e (LinkedHashMap<String, MyObj>)`

So ,you need to do another loop in side with  `${myMap.value}`

Comment: I understand your answer. But how to show the data which I can get with `myObj.getCode()` using jstl. Ex., `ADD 213412 - TEST`

Comment: Those are nested loops :Might helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488363/jstl-printing-nested-objects